# How to monitor written data from dd?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a huge disk image backed up using dd.
I need to restore the disk image but dd is very silent.

How can I monitor its progress?

Answer (score 4):

Execute the following command in the second terminal:

```
kill -USR1 nnn
```

where nnn is the PID of the running dd process.

dd will print its I/O statistics to the standard error.

Comment: Check the man page for `dd` -- in at least some versions, you need to send it SIGINFO, not SIGUSR1.

Answer (score 2):

PV should work:

```
dd if=huge_disk | pv -rb >/dev/sd_restore
```

Comment: Great idea.
Unfortunately, I already started restoring :(

Answer (score 0):

You can make the transfer happen faster by increasing the default block size for the transfer:

```
dd if=/sda bs=1M | pv -rb >/dev/sdb
```

Remember to only use this with both drives unmounted, or you could end up with a broken filesystem on the destination drive if either drive is written to during the transfer.